# Double integral - integral of a function over a ring (area between two concentric circles)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

so I have to evaluate the integral

$$\int\int xy^2 \,dx\,dy$$ where the area is bound between two concentric circles:

$x^2 + y^2 = 2$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$

After introducing polar coordinates, I get that:

1. $ r^2=2$
2. $ r^2 = 4$
3. $ \phi \in [0, 2\pi]$.

$\phi$ is bounded between these boundaries because $r$ is not a function of $\phi$ so we take the "full" angle.

Now, I have a few questions. What are the boundaries for $r$? I chose them to be $ r \in [\sqrt{2}, 2]$ but I doubt that's correct. However, whichever bounds for $r$ I use, I get that the integral evaluates to zero, because:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi) \, dr \, d\phi$$

The integral of $\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi)$ for these bounds evaluates to zero, which makes me think I chose the wrong boundaries for the angle.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You forget Jacobian, boundaries are correct.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks! But the Jacobian is simply $r$, adding another $r$ won't change anything. The integrall still evaluates to zero if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes, you did. But you should think about symmetry. The integrand is an odd function in either of two ways ($f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$) and the region is symmetric, so of course the integral is $0$.

Comment: You should have $r^4$.

Comment: @TedShifrin For some odd reason my workbook states that the answer is $\frac{4}{15} \cdot (8-\sqrt{2})$. Could the workbook be wrong?

Comment: Of course it’s wrong! But learn to take advantage of and recognize symmetry arguments!

Comment: Zero is obtained outgoing from angle in $[0,2\pi]$ and $\cos \cdot \sin^2$. Integral for $r$ gives $\frac{32-4\sqrt{2}}{5}$.

Comment: You need to remember that $dx\,dy$ does not become $dr\,d\theta,$ but rather $r\,dr\,d\theta. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is an odd function of $x$ and the region has symmetry across the $x=0$ line thus

$$I = \iint_D xy^2\:dA = -\iint_D xy^2\:dA = -I \implies I=0$$